# qfsolve in GP-Pari and finding all solutions

Tags: matrices, quadratics

GP Pari has a function called "qfsolve" which solves over Q the quadratic equation X^t G X = 0, where G is a symmetric matrix.

For example let `G = matdiagonal([1,1,-65]) =`

```
    | 1  0  0 |  
G = | 0  1  0 |  
    | 0  0 -65|
```

Running the GP Pari qfsolve(G) gives

`x = [4, 7, -1]` and double checking: `xGxT = 0` as expected.

My observation is this, there is also another vector which works as well:

`x = [1, 8, -1]` and it too satisfies the `xGxT = 0` requirement.

This vector was NOT given by qfsolve but it happens to be the other x-vector associated with G, since `4^2 + 7^2 = 1^2 + 8^2 = 65` and they are the only 2 solutions possible for 2 positive integer squares summing to 65.

Question:

How do we find ALL x-vectors which satisfy the condition?

If I take -1105 as the last term in G, there are 4 solutions possible:

`x = [24, 23, -1] x = [31, 12, -1] x = [32, 9, -1] x = [33, 4, -1]`

qfsolve(G) only gives `[32,-9,-1]` which is the 3rd solution, 3 solutions are missing.

Other than setting up a dual loop of x,y and brute forcing solutions of `x^2 + y^2 = 1105`, is there any better method of obtaining ALL the x-vector solutions using matrix operations?

Comment: In fact, your issue boils down to find rational points on a conic. No surprise that there can be many solutions...

Comment: Jean Marie, interesting. I will take a look in the literature.

Comment: Indeed $X^TGX=0$ with $G$ a symmetric matrix is a homogeneous equation for a 'projectively-defined' conic curve with $X=[x,y,t]$ or $X=[x,y,1]$. For example $G=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1}$ defines the unit circle.